# chrome extension - passing data from background to custom html page

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

Creating browser extension where I have to open new tab from background.js and pass JSON data to this new tab. In new tab I am manipulating/rendering DOM using passed JSON data.

Below is part of my background.js where I create new tab with custom URL and send JSON data object

```
.... 
var analyticsUrl = chrome.extension.getURL("analytics.html");
chrome.tabs.create({ url: analyticsUrl, selected: true }, sendDataToAnalytics);

function sendDataToAnalytics(tab)
{
    console.log(JSON.stringify(txnDataJSON));
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {"action" : "renderChartsTxns", "txns" : JSON.stringify(txnDataJSON)});
}
....
```

My custom analytics.html page has

```
<script src="analytics.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And analytics.js looks like below

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if(request.action == "renderChartsTxns")
    {
        // JSON parsing and analytics.html DOM processing
     });
```

Problem is, my analytics.js listener is never receiving any messages. I've confirmed that background.js is sending JSON message as expected (using background page debugging)

BTW, analytics.js/html are not registered as part of manifest.json file but these files are part of extension package.

I did this setup today morning and everything was working properly for few hours (was able to receive JSON data in analytics.js), not sure what changed later and I lost message receiving in analytics.js (for debugging I tried clearing browser cache, uninstall and reinstalled chrome and much more but no luck yet!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The callback of `chrome.tabs.create` returns as soon as the tab is created, not after it fully loads.

As such, you have a race condition: your message is potentially sent before the listener is initialized. Since it's a race condition, it can *sometimes* work.

The correct logic here would be to send a message *requesting* data from the newly opened tab, and use `sendResponse` to pass that data from the background.

```
// analytics.js

chrome.runtime.sendMessage({"action" : "getTxns"}, function(txns) {
  // Process the data
});

// background.js

// Register this before opening the tab
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
  if(request.action == "getTxns") {
    sendResponse(txnDataJSON); // No need to serialize yourself!
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks Xan, can you provide some example?

Comment: @Rushik Provided (had to fix the `sendMessage` I used, sorry)